# Vertica Primary Key Strange behavior

Tags: vertica

I wrote this simple piece of code in vertica 7.1.2

```
select reenable_duplicate_key_error();
create table Person(id int PRIMARY KEY, firstname varchar(20));
insert into Person select 1, 'test1' union all select 1, 'test2' union all select 1, 'test3';
```

Now if I do a

```
select * from Person;
```

i see

```
 id | firstname
----+-----------
  1 | test1
  1 | test2
  1 | test3
(3 rows)
```

so it seems there is no effect of marking a key as primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected and documented behavior. Vertica does not enforce uniqueness on load (imagine trying to ingest 500GB and having to rollback due to a PK violation). You can use analyze_constraints before committing or upgrade to 7.2 where you can enable enforcement of PK. It is still important to use keys for referential integrity.

See [my blog post](http://vertica.tips/2014/04/28/enforcing-uniqueness-of-data-on-load/) on other ways to enforce uniqueness on load.

**Update:** As of 7.2, Vertica can automatically enforce primary and unique key constraints. See the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Constraints/EnforcingPRIMARYandUNIQUEKEYConstraintsAutomatically.htm) for more information.